# Bootstrap Toggle Icon: How to hide nav menus and put inside Toggle Icon

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to hide the Nav Menus in my navbar and put them inside the toggle icon so when my browser shrink, the users can access them only from the toggle icon? I'm a beginner in CSS/Bootstrap.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Hamburger Icon -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCol">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Brand -->
            <a href="{% url 'homepage' %}" class="navbar-brand">-root- DOTA</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navCol">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="divider">
                    <a href="{% url 'teams:region_list' %}" class="navbar-link">TEAMS</a>
                </li>

                <li class="divider">
                    <a href="{% url 'matches:dota_matches' %}" class="navbar-link">MATCHES</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle{
border-color:  #041809;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
background-color:#000c07;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
width: 25px;
height: 3px;
}

.navbar-custom .nav .divider{
background-color: #000c07;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse{
background-color: #000c07;
border-color: #041809;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    ul, li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }

    .wrapper {
      max-width: 1024px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    nav { background: #eee; }

    nav .wrapper { position: relative; }

    .menu li { float: left; }

    .menu li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px 15px;
    }

    .menuToggle {
      padding: 10px 15px;
      display: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .menu {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background: #eee;
          z-index : 1;
        }

        .menu li { float: none; }

        .menuToggle { display: inline-block; }
        fh5co-nav-toggle i::before, .fh5co-nav-toggle i::after {
            content: '';
            width: 25px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #252525;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            transition: all .2s ease-out;
        }
        .fh5co-nav-toggle i {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25px;
            height: 2px;
            color: #252525;
            font: bold 14px/.4 Helvetica;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-indent: -55px;
            background: #252525;
            transition: all .2s ease-out;
        }
        .fh5co-nav-toggle.active i::after {
            bottom: 0;
            -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            -o-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            background: #c6872b;
        }

    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('.menuToggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.menu').slideToggle(300, function(){
          if($(this).css('display') === 'none'){
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="menuToggle">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu clearfix">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```